# SonarQube incremental analysis for the Code Coverage

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, sonar-runner, pre-commit, sonarqube-scan

Is it possible to run SonarQube in "Incremental" analysis mode and get not only code quality issues on the current branch but also other metrics, especially Code Coverage? (We are really interested to see how code coverage changed in the feature branch, comparing with the "develop" branch)
How this can be configured?

```
sonar.analysis.mode=incremental
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with SonarQube 5.4. We may later add this feature but this is not our top priority.

Answer (score 0):

According to [SonarSource JIRA](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-253) there is an ongoing project to support this scenario, but in a context of branches analysis (also GitHub Pull Requests). Anyone interested can track it should *vote for it* on [MMF-253](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-253).